# Files mysteriously missing in docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I create the following image:

```
FROM node:14.7.0-alpine3.12
COPY ./test.txt /home/node/app/
```

using this command:

```
docker build . -t my-test
```

The image builds successfully, I run it like this:

```
docker run -it my-test
```

I inspect the content of the folder `/home/node/app` using SSH.

So far all good.
I push the image to my docker registry.
I download the image, I run it and do the same operation. ALL GOOD. I can see the file `test.txt` is there as expected.

I try the same in other machines, it all works good.
However, in some machines, I do the same operation but the file `test.txt` is just not there. I double check the hashes, the image is correct, but the file is not in the image.

What's wrong?!

Comment: Maybe in other machines you are mounting a folder (in any level of this path `/home/node/app`)?

Comment: Hej @Yerke no I am not mounting any folder. The image does nto have any volume. I am not mounting anything at run time for sure.

Comment: @Yerke you were right, that was the issue. The problem is, the container was running in Azure Web Apps for containers and it did not show in the log that is mounting anything. But I disabled the web app storage and now works! So might be that. If you write an answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: added, check my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're mounting a volume over an existing directory you will lose the original content of your image.

In your case it might be happening because a folder is mounted in one of the levels of the path `/home/node/app`.

Use `docker inspect <container>` to monitor the list of mounted volumes inside of your container (`"Mounts"` fields).
You can also extract to output only Mounts using:
`docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' <container>`

Comment: Brilliant! This helped me resolve a conflict where an image used `/root`, and a cloud provider also mounted to `/root` by default.